# GriddB gs_cluster.json Configuration

Tags: java, griddb

I am installing GriddB server as outlined in their official site using Java and I am trying to connect to a cluster. In the [documentation](https://griddb.org/docs-en/manuals/GridDB_QuickStartGuide.html), the cluster name is set as important, and for the rest, the default values are used. Initially after installation,  my gs_cluster.json configuration looked as below[image]

However, the Java application could not connect, so I added the values that I thought were missing,namely:

```
"notificationAddress": "239.0.0.1",
"notificationPort":20000,
```

and made the final gs_cluster.json look as below.

[image]

However, nothing changed as there is not any connection yet.I have verified that my griddb server is running. Is there anything I am making wrong here? Is there a specific way to configure the gs_cluster.json file or any other related file for the connection to work ? Attached is the Java code showing how I tried to establish a connection using key-value properties.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("notificationAddress", "239.0.0.1");
    props.setProperty("notificationPort", "20000");
    props.setProperty("clusterName", "myCluster");
    props.setProperty("user", "admin");
    props.setProperty("password", "admin");
    GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance().getGridStore(props);
```

Answer (score 1):

The configuration error occurs because you presented a multicast address within your java code. You need to understand configuration mode setting for GridDB. We have Fixed List and Multicast Mode. These two operate differently.

The current GridDB 5.3.0 version is installed with a Fixed List mode i.e the configuration of cluster address on 127.0.0.1.

Now, Let's understand the two different gs_cluster.json available for use. From your question, you were referring to the gs_cluster.json in your installation folder however you should refer more to the gs_cluster.json in the **gsadm** user to understand the gs_cluster.json configuration for running GridDB. To check this GridDB gs_cluster.json configuration, make use of the following command;

```
sudo su gsadm
cd
cat conf/gs_cluster.json
```

If running these commands returns the same gs_cluster.json with 127.0.0.1 then you are confirmed to be on Fixed List Mode.

Thus, you will need to modify your java properties code as the above Gridstore configuration is configured for Multicast Mode instead of Fixed List Mode.

Fixed List Mode

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("notificationMember", "127.0.0.1:10001");
props.setProperty("clusterName", "myCluster");
props.setProperty("user", "admin");
props.setProperty("password", "admin");
GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance().getGridStore(props);
```

Thus, I will recommend you remove the added

```
"notificationAddress": "239.0.0.1",
"notificationPort":20000,
```

Since your Grid DB is configured to run on Fixed List mode.